# Unable to load a .geojson file in React

Tags: json, reactjs, geojson, react-leaflet

i'm trying to import a `.geojson` file in React using:

```
import data from 'filename.geojson';
```

but when i print the following code `console.log(data)` to check if it was load, i got this:

```
/static/media/filename.e789b00e.geojson
```

Then, if i change the file extension to `.json` instead of `.geojson`, it loads the `geoJSON` object properly. What's the problem?

I'm trying to use the geojson object in `react-leaflet` `<GeoJSON />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that webpack is using different import policies for .json files and .geojson files.

Look here: https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/

If you need to handle custom extensions as json, you need to specify it so that the json-loader is used for them too.

edit:
updated link, thanks to [NanoNova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8140523/nanonova)!

Comment: I think the link moved to [here](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/)